# Can this integral be solved analytically

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have an integral of the form

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{b_i t}}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i e^{d_i t}} dt$$

Where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$ are $4n$ real constants, and $t_1,t_2$ are positives. Is this kind of integrals solvable analytically or am i doomed to rely to numerical integration ?

Comment: If the $b_j,c_j$ are rational multiples of one real number, then the substitution $x=e^{\alpha t}$ produces a rational function, otherwise this doesn't look promising to me.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yep that is what i thaught. All constants are real numbers and not multiples of the same rational, sadly...

Comment: yet the formula for rational exponent should pass to the limit [if conveniently written,  I guess] so  I wouldn be optimistic

Comment: If this integral has closed form for real parameters, then it probably will have closed form for complex parameters too. However, no closed form exists for complex parameters. See this related question for a certain case with complex parameters and infinite limits of integration https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263541/number-theoretic-interpretation-of-the-integral-int-infty-infty-fracdx , and also this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07456

Comment: Maple fails even on this one... $$\int\frac{dt}{\exp(\pi t)+\exp(t)}$$

Comment: Conclusion is then negative, thanks for the references.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar. $$\int \frac{dt}{e^t+e^{a t}}=-e^{-t} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{1-a};\frac{a-2}{a-1};-e^{(a-1) t}\right)$$

Comment: @Pietro Majer: It is unlikely that the limit will have a "closed form".